# Prevent websites from taking over audio on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, music, music.app

An increasing number of websites like CNN.com take over the audio of my iPhone's Safari app with advertisements and pause the Music app.

How can I prevent this. I only need the audio on Safari when I am watching a video.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is jailbroken, you can install [**Don't Kill the Beat**](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=dontkillthebeatDp). This prevents apps other than Music.app from playing music. To allow an app to play music (e.g. a video in Safari), pause the music in Music.app manually yourself, such as with the Control Center.